# instance is not updated, using forms save () Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

instance is not updated, using forms save () Django.

Could anyone help?

> save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cpnj'

views

```
cliente = Cliente.objects.get(user=request.user.id, pk=pk)
 if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.update(instance=cliente, validated_data=form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect('clienteEdit', pk)
```

Forms

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data, context):
        print(instance)
        instance.save(**validated_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your model object `Cliente` and form `ClientForm` have a mismatch in one of the fields. Does your model object `Cliente` have a field called cpnj?

for updating I suggest you change the fields manually like this:

```
cliente = Cliente.objects.get(user=request.user.id, pk=pk)
 if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cliente.cpnj = form.cleaned_data['cpnj']
            cliente.save()
            return redirect('clienteEdit', pk)
```

Comment: Yes. Yes. class ClienteForm(forms.Form):

    cpnj            = forms.CharField()

Comment: class Cliente(models.Model):
    id                  = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    cpnj            = models.CharField(max_length=14)

Comment: I'm using forms.Form

Comment: i added an edit to my answer, see if that works, please note that form.cleaned_data['cpnj'] may not be correct since I dont know what its called inside the ClienteForm class